# How can I pass a state to my react-router path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

How can I add `appState` to my react router path?

I have react-redux but I'm not so sure on the most effective way to pass props to my react-router path. I tried using `withRouter` but kept getting issues.

All I want is to pass the props from one page to another.

The current error im getting is `appState` is not defined.

```
//index.js

<Route path="/dash/:slug" buckets={appState.buckets} render={props => <Bucket {...props} />} />
```

The state is coming from this:

```
//GetUserBuckets.js

export default function GetUserBuckets()
{
    const classes = useStyles();
    const ListLoading = LoadingComponent(UserBuckets);
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
        loading: true,
        posts: null,
    });


    useEffect(() =>
    {
        axiosInstance.get('all/buckets/').then((res) =>
        {
            const allBuckets = res.data;
            setAppState({ loading: false, buckets: allBuckets });
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }, [setAppState]);

    return (
        <div className={classes.text}>
            <h1>Buckets</h1>
            <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} buckets={appState.buckets} />
            <Container className={classes.createBucket}>
                    <CreateDialog />    
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: It is not clear to me. You want to access your Redux store, or you asking how to pass store variables to your Router?

Comment: I want to pass props through components, redux store would probably be the better option I think?

Comment: If you want to pass straight down to 1 component then use this:
 ``` <Route path="[pathname]" exact component={(e)=><[Component Name]  props={props}/>} />```
```exact``` is used only if you have sub-pages, because if not exact it drops you on the first match which is "/".
Or you want to pass down on multiple components? Then use Redux.

Answer (score 0):

you would pass state using router state the following shows an example in the react router dom docs https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

```
// usually all you need
<Link to="/somewhere"/>

// but you can use a location instead
const location = {
  pathname: '/somewhere',
  state: { fromDashboard: true }
}

<Link to={location}/>
<Redirect to={location}/>
history.push(location)
history.replace(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it via Route prop - you can use location prop (location.state), link below

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

But in general pass data through Route component is not best idea, because if user follows via link to this specific component - state will be not attached to the location prop.

And in your case Route should be in the render (return) method of GetUserBuckets component

Comment: Generally, how would you recommend I pass props through my components?

Comment: Pass data via props is good idea from Parent to Child component. But sometimes it could be impossible, so in real apps developers use "global state" libraries like Redux, MobX or React Context api

Comment: I have redux, would you mind showing me how to do it using redux ?

Comment: Redux is a bit confusing for React beginners, try to learn from this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVpUuw9XSjY

Comment: Thank you for the link. Yes im indeed confused with all the options out there available to accomplish my task :)

Comment: Not only you, Redux is most confusing library in React world, watch Youtube videos about React and with time and practice you will understand it better and better :-)